# Error when using datatables callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatables table set up to call json from a server.  I would like to be able to easily format the rows based on the data in each row much like this:

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

So I am using the code in that link with my code like so:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        testTable = $('#myList').DataTable({

            // My current proprerties and ajax stuff


            "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                if (My own conditional) {
                    $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
                }
            }
       })
```

However when I run this I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I am fairly new to jQuery and especially datatables so I'm not certain of where to start with this.  Has anyone come across it before?

Comment: It's going to be hard to help if we can't see your `current properties` and `conditional`. Sounds like your data is `undefined`, since `replace` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it would be very useful to see the actual condition and maybe also the HTML. Maybe you tried to use an index of data that doesn't exist?

Comment: Even if you only had 5 or less columns it would not be the code provided that causes the problem.  It is inside "My own conditional" or elsewhere.